# Why does the output in following command get written to second file rather than first file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I was learning about I/O redirection and tried out the following command.

```
ls -l /bin/ > bin_contents.txt > bin_contents_copy.txt
```

I do understand that redirection doesn't work between files. But, on running the command, I expected the output stream data of the ls command to be stored in the first file i.e. **bin_contents.txt**. Since the output stream redirection from ls command is given directly to this file. And expected the second file, **bin_contents_copy.txt** file to be empty (since redirection doesn't work between files).

But when I ran the command, I found the contrary to be true. The output stream of ls command is stored in the second file i.e. **bin_contents_copy.txt** rather than the file **bin_contents.txt**. Why does that happen?